# Returning the number of unique numbers in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, return, return-value

I was asked to write a method that accepts a **sorted array**, removes any duplicate elements found in the array and then places a 0 at the end of the array for every duplicate element found.

It is also supposed to return the number of unique elements found in the array.

Here is my method:

```
public static int removeDups(int[] arr) {
    int j = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int numDups = 0;

    while(i < arr.length) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            i++;     
            numDups++;       
        } 
        else {
            arr[++j] = arr[i++];
        }   
    }

    for (int k = j+1; k < arr.length; k++) {
        arr[k] = 0;     
    }

    return (j); 
}
```

It successfully finds all the duplicate numbers in the array and places the correct number of 0s at the end, but it doesn't always return the correct value for the number of unique elements.

For example, for the array:

```
{ 6 10 19 21 23 26 27 36 38 45 }
```

the number of unique elements should be 10, but it returns 9.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't use that method since I'm not allowed to use nested loops and any element in the array can be moved at most once.

Comment: Can't you just return `j + 1`? That's what your doing when you set `k = j + 1` to add the zeroes.

Comment: You are using `j` to keep the index of last unique number. So the count of unique numbers is `j + 1`. Just return `j + 1` at the end.

Comment: @JonnyHenly If I return (j+1), the value returned is still wrong and not equal to the number of unique elements.

Comment: You said it returns 9 but should return 10, 9 + 1 ='s 10. That's just for the example array you provided us with, what does an array with duplicates look like before and after?

Comment: How do you plan to keep track of duplicates?  Even this detail is not so clear right now.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace I tried with several arrays including the one you provided. All worked fine as per the requirement given in your question when you return `j + 1` at the end

Comment: @LahiruChandima If I return (j+1), for the array: { 2 11 12 15 28 40 40 42 42 45 } it returns 9, when it should return 8.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried to keep track of duplicates earlier by adding a variable numDups and doing numDups++ inside the first if statement, but when I tried to return (arr.length - numDups), the value returned was still wrong.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace I don't know why you get 9, but I get 8 when I tried `{ 2 11 12 15 28 40 40 42 42 45 }`. If I return `j` instead of `j + 1`, I get 7

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I wasn't trying to answer vaguely. I have now edited the question and added my implementation for counting the number of duplicates.

Comment: @LahiruChandima I don't know why we are getting different values. Are you sure you're using exactly the same code as what I put down in the question?

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace. Yes. I even used your edited code and gives me 8. Check this. http://pasteboard.co/18J3N2kM.jpg

Comment: @LahiruChandima Well.. I guess then I have no idea why it won't work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace Also try this http://ideone.com/MmiEn8. You can run your code online and check

Comment: In first look, when two entries in array are same you attempt to shift later one to prior one But shouldn't that code(arr[++j] = arr[i++];) be inside if rather than else.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem.  It keeps track of two pointers, one which only advances when a value gets *written* to the array, and the other which touches every element of the array in sequential order.  When one or more duplicates are encountered, the second pointer keeps advancing, while the first pointer stays put, waiting to write a non-duplicate value.  Finally, the code iterates over the remainder of the array from the first pointer, writing out zeroes until the end.

```
public static int removeDups(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (arr.length == 0 || arr.length == 1) {
        return arr;
    }

    int prevIndex = 0;

    for (int i=1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[prevIndex] != arr[i]) {
            arr[prevIndex+1] = arr[i];
            ++prevIndex;
        }
    }

    for (int i=prevIndex+1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }

    return prevIndex+1;
}

int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 10};
removeDups(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0]
```

This code has been tested using IntelliJ and it appears to be working.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace Please review this answer, thanks.

Comment: This does work to remove the duplicates and place the 0s, but it doesn't return the number of unique elements.

Comment: Theoretically, this should work, just like @Lahiru's answer should work, but for me it is still returning the wrong value. Though this is probably because of an unrelated problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your code has a number of problems.  Do you want me to start with your code instead and attempt an answer?

Comment: Sure, if you'd like to, @Tim!

Comment: Your code looks completely fine to me.  It runs in my IntelliJ with no problems at all.

Comment: I am not able to understand the impact of code: arr[++j] = arr[i++]; This piece code would copy an array element to itself when j and i have consecutive values.Please tell me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: He is advancing his `j` pointer by one, then assigning at that place to the current `i` pointer.  After this, `i` gets incremented by one.  What is confusing here?

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen, `j` is used as the index of the last unique element.

In an array, `i`'th index is actually the `i + 1`'th element counted from 1.

So, you have to return `j + 1` instead of `j` from your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
static int getUniqueElements(int [] sortedArr){

        int duplicateCount = 0;
        int [] tempArr = sortedArr;
        int j=0;
        boolean isNewValue = true;
        for(int i=1;i<tempArr.length;i++){
            if(sortedArr[j] != tempArr[i]){
                isNewValue = true;
                sortedArr[++j] = tempArr[i];
            }else{
                if(isNewValue){
                    isNewValue = false;
                    duplicateCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        for(j++;j<sortedArr.length;j++){
            sortedArr[j] = 0;
            duplicateCount++;
        }

        return (sortedArr.length-duplicateCount);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8};
        System.out.println("Unique Count:"+ getUniqueElements(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

OutPut:

```
Unique Count:2
[1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Since in the given array 1,7 are unique.

***Note***: tried with your example array `{6, 10, 19, 21, 23 ,26 ,27 ,36 ,38, 45 }` also

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as(assuming elements can repeat only twice):

```
public static int removeDups(int[] arr) {       
    int i = 0;
    int numDups = 0;
    while (i < arr.length - 1 - numDups) {          
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
            numDups++;
            for (int m = i + 1; m < arr.length - numDups; m++) {
                arr[m] = arr[m + 1];
            }
            arr[arr.length - numDups] = 0;
        }           
        i++;
    }
    return arr.length-numDups;
}
```